# Linq-To-Sql convert string to date with specific format

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a date stored as a string in a not so good format (dd-MM-yyyy). The SQL server cannot automatically convert this into a date, at least not with the settings that are on it, but with a little help it fixes it. The following SQL statement works perfectly:

```
select * from table
where convert(date,myValue,105) < GETDATE()
```

Problem I have is, how do I do this in LINQ? I tried different things manually and I tested *Linqer* to generate LINQ from my SQL. This is what Linqer gives me:

```
from table in db.table
where
  Convert.ToDateTime(myValue) < DateTime.Now
select new {
  ...
}
```

Problem is, when I run the statement above I get:

*The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

Probably because it drops the **105** parameter to the convert method. I've tried different parse methods (Parse, ParseExact and Convert.ToDateTime with an IFormatProvider) but all those give me errors that are more or less like:

*Method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' has no supported translation to SQL.*

So my question is, is there a good way to convert a date with an "odd" dateformat in Linq so that I will get working T-SQL? I already have a "working" solution, but I would like to know if there's any way to get Linq to interpret this in a nice way?

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not the best practice but if it works then so be with it, I suggest you create a View in your table

```
  CREATE VIEW view_table 
  AS 
  select tbl_id, 
         convert(date,myValue,105) as myDate
  from table
```

so then from your linq

```
     from table in db.view_table
        where
        Convert.ToDateTime(myDate) < DateTime.Now
   select new {
      ...
   }
```

because the column myValue is already converted to 105 format.

Comment: That is a possible solution, but I was more interested in solving it with linq without having to create new stuff in the database.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to convert them locally with using `AsEnumerable` and `DateTime.ParseExact`.

```
from table in db.table.AsEnumerable()
where
  DateTime.ParseExact(myValue, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < DateTime.Now
select new {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this. But this solution will load all the data into memory right?

Comment: Yes. So I think Blaire Andaloc's answer is better than mine from performance point of view:)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to parse out the parts manually and build a new DateTime

```
from table in db.table
let myValue = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(yourdate.Substring(6,4)),Convert.ToInt32(yourdate.Substring(3,2)),Convert.ToInt32(yourdate.Substring(0,2)))
where
  myValue < DateTime.Now
```

select new {
  ...
}

yourdate is a date in string dd-MM-yyyy format